# Google Fusion Tables API results in Bad Request

Tags: php, magento, google-fusion-tables

I am using the Google Fusion Tables API to get rows from a Fusion Table (I am intending to update those rows but am trying to keep it simple until I get the connection right). The table is set to Unlisted and Downloadable in its settings. I have the API key right since the request works fine when I load it in a browser, but when I execute my code I get a Bad Request response from Google. Below is the code I am using:

NOTE: I am not using Oauth at this time to authenticate the request. The documentation states that this is not necessary if you are using a GET string and sql statements to manipulate the data. The key below should work from any source, but I intend to switch to a server key for security.

```
$sellerlist = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('partnerstatus',array('eq'=>'Seller'))->addFieldToFilter('wantpartner',array('eq'=>1)); 
foreach($sellerlist as $seller){
            $profileurl = Mage::getUrl()."marketplace/seller/profile/".$seller->getProfileurl();
            if($seller->getshoptitle()!=''){ $shoptitle = $seller->getshoptitle();}
             else {  $shoptitle = $seller->getprofileurl(); }
            $logo=$seller->getlogopic()==''?"noimage.png":$seller->getlogopic();
            $logo=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'avatar/'.$logo;
            $latitude = $seller->getlatitude();
            $longitude = $seller->getlongitude();
            if ($latitude !== ''){


                $req = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT ROWID FROM 12rLP9qGYclz-kkDa_y_NJ1Meh81EZK_5o7yp38sk WHERE shoptitle='".$shoptitle."'&key=AIzaSyAqt5biL_4nsZ25ZZC1RaeClssOIhXkn_k"));
                curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);


                $responseJSON = curl_exec($req);
                $resp = json_decode($responseJSON, true);
                curl_close($req);

                print_r($responseJSON);


            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't encode the complete URL, you must only encode the GET-parameters(`http_build_query` will be a good choice for it):

```
curl_setopt($req, 
        CURLOPT_URL, 
        'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?'
          .http_build_query(array('sql'=>
                                    "SELECT ROWID 
                                      FROM 12rLP9qGYclz-kkDa_y_NJ1Meh81EZK_5o7yp38sk 
                                      WHERE shoptitle='{$shoptitle}'",
                                  'key'=>'AIzaSyAqt5biL_4nsZ25ZZC1RaeClssOIhXkn_k')));
```

Comment: That fixed it! The API key I'm using here is an open one (unrestricted) - I'll use a different one for my application. Thanks!